# How to I enable my fingerprint reader on my ThinkPad X1 Yoga (Gen 2) in Ubuntu 21.10?

Tags: gnome, login, thinkpad, fingerprint-reader

I've just installed the latest Ubuntu 21.10 on my new-to-me ThinkPad X1 Yoga Gen 2.  I've kept the stock DE, Gnome 40.4.0.  I'm working off Ubuntu's [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/session-fingerprint.html.en), but I'm stuck on step 3:

> Press on Disabled, next to Fingerprint Login to add a fingerprint for the selected account. If you are adding the fingerprint for a different user, you will first need to Unlock the panel.

The "Disabled" button/option is not appearing for me. (See screenshot below.)

[image: No Disabled Button]

The same support page says that this should work if my system has a "supported fingerprint scanner", but I cannot find documentation of the list of supported fingerprint scanners or how to determine if mine is.

I have tried installing various fingerprint packages from other StackOverflow/Reddit support requests etc., but they seem to be for different Ubuntu versions or different hardware.

How may I enable my fingerprint reader?

Edit: Including the requested output of `sudo lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 138a:0097 Validity Sensors, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:5682 IMC Networks SunplusIT Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 056a:50b6 Wacom Co., Ltd Pen and multitouch sensor
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Edit 2 - The [thread Dave proposed](https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/i0mkw1/thinkpad_x1_carbon_4th_ubuntu_2004_fingerprint/) has me install the PPA, which fails.  Console output from the attempt to install is here.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:3v1n0/libfprint-vfs0090
Repository: 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/3v1n0/libfprint-vfs0090/ubuntu/ impish main'
Description:
  Validity Fingerprint 138a:0090 and 138a:0097 (experimental) driver for Linux

- It needs to be paired with your computer using this tool:
  https://github.com/3v1n0/python-validity, install it via snap:
  
  # Initialize the device
  sudo snap install validity-sensors-tools
sudo snap connect validity-sensors-tools:raw-usb
sudo snap connect validity-sensors-tools:hardware-observe
sudo validity-sensors-tools.initializer

# For validity 0097 you also need to enroll the fingers in chip
sudo validity-sensors-tools.initializer --finger-id [0...9]

- Sources and more information at
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/3v1n0/libfprint-tod-vfs0090
https://github.com/3v1n0/libfprint
More info: https://launchpad.net/~3v1n0/+archive/ubuntu/libfprint-vfs0090
Adding repository.
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel.
Found existing deb entry in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/3v1n0-ubuntu-libfprint-vfs0090-impish.list
Adding deb entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/3v1n0-ubuntu-libfprint-vfs0090-impish.list
Found existing deb-src entry in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/3v1n0-ubuntu-libfprint-vfs0090-impish.list
Adding disabled deb-src entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/3v1n0-ubuntu-libfprint-vfs0090-impish.list
Adding key to /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/3v1n0-ubuntu-libfprint-vfs0090.gpg with fingerprint BE6CFC9508199102F68B6F683166F0E44FB01EAB
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease                                                                                   
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports InRelease                                                                                 
Hit:4 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                               
Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/3v1n0/libfprint-vfs0090/ubuntu impish InRelease
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu impish InRelease
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/3v1n0/libfprint-vfs0090/ubuntu impish Release
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/3v1n0/libfprint-vfs0090/ubuntu impish Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Is the Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Yoga (Gen 2) fingerprint reader one of the supported readers reference on Ubuntu's documentation page?  How can I determine that?

Comment: Not all fingerprint readers have drivers available for Linux. Could you [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo lsusb`? This will show some hardware IDs that will make it easier to identify if your reader has a working driver or not 

Comment: Check this thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/i0mkw1/thinkpad_x1_carbon_4th_ubuntu_2004_fingerprint/ not offering it as an answer as it's old, hits on an external ppa, and I can't test it myself. Ultimately if I'm remembering right my finger print scanner wouldn't work for driver issues as well on the same machine, wasn't important enough to me to fix so I never did. :(